# Tracking Production Bug

Tags: findbugs, dev-to-production

We have huge deployment coming up! 
Problem here is its issue when we go live in waterfall method where everything is getting tested all together.
So scary part is the list of bug and tracking it back to source, whether it was code or requirement issue in both business and IT.
How should I maintain sanity with all the teams involved and how to track production bug and assigned to right team?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds so familiar. You need a tool to track your defects and requirements a so called Application lifecycle management tool ([ALM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_lifecycle_management))
I (was forced) to use [(na)HP ALM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Application_Lifecycle_Management) in the past to track everything.  I personally dislike this tool because it is quite old and cumbersome but it serves its purpose. I have also worked with [Polarion](https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/polarion-alm) and now a days most (modern) projects use jira to track everything. No matter what tool you are using but you need ONE single source of truth - a tool which is used by the business people, the developers and the testers...

But you tagged your question with [spotbugs (findbugs)](https://spotbugs.github.io/) which could also point in the direction of code quality analysis. Additionally to ensure quality we use the (free) [sonar server](https://www.sonarqube.org/) to detect bugs in the code. It also has the possibility to assign those bugs to the developers and track it over its lifcycle. It always makes sense to use spotbugs / sonar and the like to ensure code quality.